# Is there no named character entity references in HTML for the "@" char?

Tags: html

Searched this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for "@" but no joy. Any explanations for the omission.

I now realise using any such entity is futile as effective protection from spam bots scrapping addresses but that's where I was coming from.

Comment: `&commat; ` =  @ see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html#named-character-references for the current full set of named charcater references.

Comment: “Why” questions are not constructive. I suppose the question should be interpreted as asking “Is there...”

Comment: Why is the most constructive question one can ask, but I take your point, they are a no-go on SO :-) Will edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no named character entity reference for `@` because it is a printable character(i.e. it is from the first 128 characters that are part of the standard ASCII) with no special meaning for both xml and html. As for protection from spam bots I don't think it would be any more difficult for them to parse `&at;` for instance than `@`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Alohci mentions in a comment, there is the named character reference `&commat;` in “WHATWG HTML Living Standard”, and is also present in W3C HTML5 CR. There is however no point in using it, since even relatively new browsers do not recognize this (pointless) addition to HTML. In the rare case where your keyboard settings are odd and you don’t know how to type “@” and you have no convenient way of cutting and pasting it, you can use the character reference `&#x40;` or, equivalently, `&#64;`.

You cannot get protection against spam bots by using character references. It is trivial for spam bot authors to deal with them.